# How to get sphinx to document a package's __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, boost-python

I have a package I would like to document with sphinx. The package consists of a few native modules (generated using boost-python) and an `__init__.py`

The `__init__.py` does a bunch of (documented) monkey patching of the boost-python modules and provides a bunch of convenience functions.

I haven't been able to figure out how to tell sphinx to generate package level documentation based on the `__init__.py`. All I've found in my searching is how to get sphinx to generate documentation from a class `__init__` method, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: `.. automodule:: yourpackage` should work, with the `:members:` option.

Comment: @mzjn I actually ran `sphinx-apidoc -f ...` and `.. automodule:: mypackage` was generated along with the `:members:` option. No luck. :(

Comment: Tested today, still an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just use the command `sphinx-apidoc -f -e -o ./source ..` and for my packages in "Module contents" section of documentation I got docstrings from `__init__.py`. By the way, you should have a look at the imports in the modules - while I had some wrong imports, these files were skipped. After fixes I got documentation.